# Error monitor for different applications

Tags: error-handling, frameworks, monitoring, error-reporting, health-monitoring

Currently we have many applications, where each application has its own error notification and reporting mechanism, so we clearly have many problems:

- Lack of consistent error monitoring across different systems/applications: different GUIs, interfaces, different messages, etc.
- Different approaches for error notification per application (many applications use email notifications, other applications publish messages to queue, etc.).
- Separated configuration settings for reporting and monitoring per application: notification frequency, message recipients, etc.

You could add many other issues to the list, but the point is clear. Currently there is a plan to develop a custom application or service to provide a consistent and common solution for this situation.

Anyway, I am not sure if it is a good idea to create a custom application for this, I am sure that there should be a framework, platform or an existing solution or product (preferentially open source) that already solves this problem, so my question is: **do you know what project or product to check before deciding to create our custom application?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much information is written to application logs, you could consider using Hyperic. It's open source and has a lot of the features you are looking for.

http://www.hyperic.com/

Comment: Oh, that one looks good, do you know how easy it is to customize for existing applications? Thanks.

Comment: That would most likely depend on your requirements. I know Hyperic has capabilities for monitoring / parsing application logs and generating alerts off of what it finds. It wasn't too difficult to get up and running. Perhaps you could prototype a couple of notifications as a proof of concept to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: I'm not going to use Hyperic, but I took a lot of features and ideas from Hyperic in order to check other options and evaluate what we could do if we go with an in-house option. We haven't made a decission, but I think we'll go with a third party tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [AlertGrid](http://alert-grid.com), it works as a centralized event handler, and notification dispatcher. It can collect events from different sources and you can easily manage event handling by creating rules in a visual editor. So, you can filter events, and raise notifications (email, sms, phone - works worldwide) whenever your custom condition is met. You can react not only to events that ocurred but also the ones that did not occur (detect missing 'heartbeats'). All you need is to feed AlertGrid with events (Signals), by a very simple API.

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for. I'm in the AlertGrid dev team, if you had any questions - feel free to ask. We constantly develop this tool and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I will check this option later since I cannot access my personal email at this moment (for my account activation). Just one question, can AlertGrid be deployed internally in my network? Because I think my company won't be willing to send or use a public web server. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. AlertGrid is available as a product. Contact us for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Bugsnag is an awesome option if you are looking to do cross platform error monitoring. It supports some 50 platforms in one interface. https://blog.bugsnag.com/react-native-plus-code-push/